# Destroy Concourse pipeline that is named like an instanced pipeline

Tags: concourse

I have created a Concourse pipeline that is named like "mypipeline/branch:mybranch".  That name makes it look like an instanced pipeline, but it's not.  I can't delete it or rename it.  I can see it listed and I can see its ID when I run `fly -t ... pipelines --all`.

When I run destroy-pipeline against it I get:

```
fly -t [...] destroy-pipeline -p "mypipeline/branch:mybranch" --team=myteam
!!! this will remove all data for pipeline `mypipeline/branch:mybranch`

are you sure? [yN]: y
`mypipeline/branch:mybranch` does not exist
```

I can't figure out how to destroy it using the ID, or a wildcard, or how to rename it. Is there any way to get rid of this pipeline?